# Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception ERROR

Tags: exception, ftp, zend-framework

I have try to simulate and develop base of some zend project
and in first step I copy all FTP file & folder to my local computer
but application send me below error (in loading plugin from source )

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name '_' in C:\wamp\Mina\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php on line 398
( ! ) Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception: Plugin by name '_' was not found in the registry; used paths: Mina_View_Helper_: Mina/View/Helper/ App_View_Helper_: App/View/Helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:/wamp/Mina/application/modules/default/views\helpers/ in C:\wamp\Mina\library\Zend\Loader\PluginLoader.php on line 398
```

even some plug in exsist that hides in var_dumped error array in pluginloader.php line 398
like this:

```
string 'Db' (length=2)
array
  'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
    array
          0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
string 'Translate' (length=9)
array
          'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
        array
      0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
string 'Layout' (length=6)
array
      'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
string 'Frontcontroller' (length=15)
array
  'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
string 'ViewRenderer' (length=12)
array
  'Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/' (length=30)
string 'Navigation' (length=10)
array
  'Mina_View_Helper_' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Mina/View/Helper/' (length=16)
  'App_View_Helper_' => 
array
  0 => string 'App/View/Helper/' (length=16)
  'Zend_View_Helper_' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Zend/View/Helper/' (length=17)
          1 => string './views\helpers/' (length=16)
    string 'View' (length=4)
    array
      'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
        array
      0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
    string 'Modules' (length=7)
    array
      'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
        array
              0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
        string 'Router' (length=6)
    array
      'Zend_Application_Resource_' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Zend/Application/Resource/' (length=26)
    string 'Word_CamelCaseToDash' (length=20)
    array
      'Zend_Filter_' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Zend/Filter/' (length=12)
    string 'StringToLower' (length=13)
    array
      'Zend_Filter_' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Zend/Filter/' (length=12)
```

that mines some plugins doesn't exist 
but original project works with this situation

in further convey i find that index.php references some library that i cant see with any tricks on FTP server 
(Line 5 Of Below Code:)

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/models"),
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/forms"), 
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

[tree map of original project Going on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBki8.png)

in further there is not any navigation.php in my library folder not like that errors says (except zendframework classes)

and every of this namespace (and view helpers)  are registred in application.ini

because no plugins have runs no page are displayed.
Share me if you had any idea about this error

Comment: I am not being rude. I understand english is not your language. But PLEASE try to express yourself better because I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: if something is nontransparent please tell me to describe more. my project work on server but not work on local windows machine . with some library pass that not exist in ftp folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is the correct answer, but its worth a shot...

The simplest way I could think of to reproduce this error myself was to insert the following code into one of my views:

```
<?php echo $this->_( 'Some text' );?>
```

This suggests to me that *maybe* your application uses the **gettext** module for language translation, and maybe it is configured on your server but not on your local machine. Running phpinfo() should confirm this fairly quickly. This is the only explanation I can deduce from the information I have gleaned from your question.

Of course, if somebody *had* used **gettext** to multi-lingualize the app, I'm pretty sure they would not have included "$this->" before the underscore, so this is a bit of an anomaly in my answer.

Comment: Hi
What's your oponion about referencing to Library that doesn't exist?(in line 5 of index.php)

Comment: Whilst there is, from a technical standpoint, no problem in including a folder in your include path that doesn't exist, it is unnecessary and unclean and suggests to me that somebody, somewhere along the line, wasn't quite sure what they were doing so they just added stuff until the application worked but then didn't spend the time removing the bits that didn't work. Just remove line 5 and if the application breaks, add it back and then try removing line 4, because only one of those references is probably needed (unless, of course, you actually *do* have two library folders...)